# How to save a sqlite database when using Datagrip from Jetbrains

Tags: sqlite, datagrip

Something I can't get my head around. When I use Sqlite in the console I can do `.save test.sqlite`.

But how can I save my database to a file when I am inside the Jetbrains datagrip console?

I tried this:

[image]

But is does not work. When I search for this on the internet I find how to export data in general within datagrip, but that is not where I'm looking for.

I hope there is some way to to this. Datagrip is handy if it comes to geopackages, for only if I could save them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sqlite-jdbc has two additional statements: `backup` & `restore`, see
[their docs](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/blob/master/Usage.md#how-to-use-online-backup-and-restore-feature). So it does exactly the same as `.save`

But I'm not sure you need it. When you call `.save` in command line client, it just copies current database to specified location.
In DataGrip you usually open existing database and work with that. All changes will be reflected in opened file (taking transactions & Co into account). So no reason to "save" your work.

Comment: In my experience, it does not save the in memory database. Therefor I wanted to trigger the save manually.

Comment: So you are using in-memory database in DG and wanted to save it to the file?

Comment: Well the problem in my case is that I opened the file with Datagrip, and another external process is doing something with the geopackage. So sometimes it is locked, or just removed. And in the last case the in memory database still functions, since Datagrip can query the tables. But the file is gone. I did some manual work and did not want it to get wasted. So I thought why can't I use `.backup` or `.save` inside Datagrip console. Any way my work was lost and I just redid it. So if the answer is 'you can not', I'll accept that.

Comment: @botenvouwer I've update an answer, there are statements to save/restore DB: `backup` & `restore`, they just named differently
If your external process can remove database file, mb it's better to save your work in separate file? You can create separate database for your work and `ATTACH` that externally modified file to your session. (you may want to enable `single connection mode` in DG, so it will use the same session to show the content of DB)

Comment: As addition, if you delete a lot of data use the `VACUUM;` command inside Datagrip to purge deleted records from file.